# Compactness of the set of functions majorized by an increasing function

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, compactness, topological-vector-spaces

Let $L$ be the set of all integrable real-valued functions defined over $[0,1)$. The set $L$ is a topological vector space (TVS) with addition of functions $f+g$ and multiplication of a function with a real number defined in the usual way.

Consider a nonnegative increasing function $f\in L$ and the subset $$S=\left\{g\in L: g \textrm{ is nonnegative and increasing,}\\ \int_{z}^1 g(x)\leq \int_z^1 f(x), \forall z\in[0,1), \\ \int_{0}^1 g(x)= \int_0^1 f(x)\right\}.$$
My question is: is $S$ a compact set? why?

**My idea:** define a metric $M$ by defining the distance between two functions $g,h$ as $\int_0^1 |g(x)-h(x)|dx$, and then showing that $L$ is compact "with respect to" this metric.

**A relevant question:** The TVS $L$ is metrizable. Suppose we prove that $L$ is compact "with respect to" a metric $M$. This TVS might not be compact "with respect" to some metric $N$ though. Then compactness is not a property of the TVS; it is rather a property of a pair (TVS, Metric). If this is right, then, how should one interpret theorems that simply mention compactness, but no metric. For example [Bauer's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer_maximum_principle) requires a convex and compact set, but would compactness  with respect to any metric be sufficient for this principle to hold?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Generally simple Problem Statement Questions aren't looked upon well here without some effort of your own

Comment: @Alan I have tried. The problem is when $f$ goes to infinity at 1. Then, one issue that I have is about proving boundedness: can we, e.g.? argue that $|\int_0^1 f(x) dx|$ is a norm, so integrability guarantees boundedness?

Comment: Integrability doesn't guarantee boundedness.  $x^{\frac {-1 } 2}$ is integrable on $(0,1]$ but not bounded

Comment: @alan I don't mean boundedness of the function, but the set $S$. We can have sets of unbounded functions that are bounded (the set, not the function). At least I see this can happen according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Neighborhoods_and_open_sets. No? So my problem is showing that $S$ is bounded  (according to the definition of boundedness in topological vector spaces, although $S$ itself may contain unbounded functions)

Comment: Ahh.  Then I don't think you are bounded here,  because you can have your functions $g$ be as far below $f$ as you want.  Define $g_n(x)=f(x)-n$

Comment: @Alan. My bad, I had forgotten to write $g$ is nonnegative in the definition of $S$. I updated the definition. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alan I'd appreciate it if you can give any hints! thanks. Now I have also included my idea and the reason I cannot make it formal.

Comment: I gave the start of a sequential idea below.  Pretty sure it should work, if it doesn't figuring out where it fails should be instructive

Comment: A note of caution. Bounded + closed does not always imply compactness; a counterexample is the unit sphere in an infinite-dimensional normed vector space.

Answer (score 1):

This angle might work on sequential compactness.   Take an arbitrary sequence $\{g_i\}$ in your space.  Now,  we know $0\leq g_i(0)\leq f(0)$,  so $a_0=\sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \{f(0)-g(i)\}$ exists and we can take a subsequence of $g$  such that $g_i(0)$ monotonically increases with $\lim_{i\to \infty}g_i(0)=a_0$.   Do that, then relabel the sequence accordingly (Otherwise we'd get into sub sub subscripts with this argument!).   So now we have a subsequence with monotonic $g_i(0)$.   Do the exact same with $g_i(1)$.

Now we have a subsequence that approaches the same start point and the same end point,  but it might not be increasing all the way.   So we bifurcate.   Do the same for $g(\frac 1 2)$.    Then $g(\frac 1 4)$ and $g(\frac 3 4)$.   Repeat for all $g(\frac n {2^k})$.   At each step we refine our sequence to one that increases to the limit values at finer and finer divisions.  I'm about 99% certain you can then show this must converge to an increasing function $g$ in your space.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I see how it can go. To be sure: when you say convergence, do you mean  convergence with respect to the norm I defined earlier in the problem statement? If yes, then I guess the limit might not be unique (i.e., the sequence can converge to multiple functions that are equal almost everywhere)

Comment: In function metric spaces where the metric is given by an integral norm,  technically we don't look at individual functions but equivalence classes of functions that are equal almost everywhere.   (IE all functions that are equal A.E. are the "same" function".  And yes, in that metric.

Comment: Thanks. This is my last question, then I'll write a formal argument here and accept your answer too. Suppose we have proved your claim. That proves compactness "with respect to" the metric we defined (call it M). This topological vector space (TVS) might not be compact "with respect" to some metric N though. Then compactness is not a property of the TVS; it is rather a property of a pair (TVS, Metric). If this is right, then, how should one interpret theorems that simply mention compactness, but no metric (such as Bauer's maximum principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer_maximum_principle)

Comment: @afshi7n Unfortunately I haven't worked with TVSs in general so I'm not sure,  probably should find someone with more experience there.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Metrizability not all TVSs are metrizable, so yeah, this argument might not work in general.

Comment: Yes, compactness depends on the topology/metric with which the space is endowed. In fact, for every vector space there is a metric that prevents "almost all" subsets of this space from being compact: the discrete metric where every point has distance $0$ to itself and any two different points have distance $1$. With respect to this metric every singleton set is open and therefore every at least countable subset of the vector space is not compact. The Bauer maximum principle assumes that a vector space $X$ with some topology $\tau$ (or metric $d$) is given.